# Crear variables con números en javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo una variable i=0. Y ahora quiero crea una variable que se llame j0 concatenado j e i.¿Se podría hacer de alguna manera?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es crear una variable ***j*** seguido del valor contenido en ***i*** (ejemplo: si ***i=9*** entonces ***j9=i***), puedes hacerlo con la función `eval(..)`.

Ejemplo:

```js
// crear j0 partiendo del valor de i = 0: (j0=0):
var i=0;
eval("j"+i+"="+i);

// crear j9 partiendo del valor de i = 9: (j9=9):
var i=9;
eval("j"+i+"="+i);

// desplegar los valores de j0 y j9:
console.log("j0 = " + j0);
console.log("j9 = " + j9);
```

Comment: En general, usar eval se considera una mala práctica.

Comment: @PabloLozano tienes razón pero mas que cuestionar lo que el OP esta haciendo, SO esta para dar soluciones.

Comment: Hacer que el OP se cuestione lo que está haciendo puede ser parte de la solución. No hay buenos motivos para hacer lo que el OP pide.

Comment: Qué es el OP? @PabloLozano

Comment: significado de OP: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1304/35232

Answer (score 1):

se le llaman array o arreglos.

```js
var j=[]
for (var i=0;i<10;i++){
     j[i]=i*10;
}
r.innerHTML=j[0];   
s.innerHTML=j[1];   
t.innerHTML=j[2];
u.innerHTML=j;
```

```html
<p id='r'></p>
<p id='s'></p>
<p id='t'></p>
<p id='u'></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tambien puedes con este codigo:

```
var numero=1;    
window["nombre_de_tu_variable"+numero]
```

Donde numero seria lo que convierte tu variable en una variable dinamica.